# Magento 2: Invoice PDF Can't Complete Download on Customer End "Failed - Network Error"

Tags: magento2, error, invoice, pdf

I have an extension by MageSpaceX that creates PDFs for Invoice/Order PDF. It works fine on the Admin End, I can hit "Print PDF", and it generates it perfectly. Downloads it, and I can do whatever I want with it as an admin.

But when I login on the customer-end and go to Order History, open the same order, and hit "Print Custom PDF" under Invoice, a new window opens, a download starts for the same PDF I was able to see on the admin side of things, but it keeps "downloading", it's a 53KB file, until it times out and states "Failed - Network Error" on Chrome and "Failed" on Safari. This has happened 20+ times, and it always works on the Admin end.

Does anyone have any ideas of the cause, and perhaps a fix for this? In Chrome, before the item times out, if I change the "incomplete file" to .pdf from .part, the file is fine. It opens perfectly. Something is just not letting chrome "finish" the download.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? We are having the same problem as well. Thanks. -Gunardi

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159250)

Comment: Did you solve this issue?